# Ubuntu 14.04 does not detect my wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless

So I've been using Ubuntu and I find one problem everyday, that is Ubuntu never detects my WiFi network whenever I switch it on. I need to either reboot my router / laptop to get it connected.

[image: My Network page on Ubuntu]

The last one is my. 
I have a Broadcomm BCM43142 [14e4:4365] wireless adapter.
I have tried using Connect to a Hidden WiFi network, deleting my WiFi data from the laptop.
It still does not recognize my home network while it recognizes all other networks.

Posting this from Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by changing my router's channel to 6. It was on 13 and Ubuntu wasn't able to detect it. Don't know why.